# How to parse / extract data from GET based parameters in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, urlparse

I have over a thousand links which all have GET based parameters.

```
https://us.webuy.com/search/index.php/"><script>prompt(/XSS/)</script>
https://www.densuke.biz/help
http://www.ntrcars.co.uk/email.php?subject=%22%3E%3Csvg/onload=alert(/XSS/)%3E
http://www.americanexpress.com/thailand/en/leave_country.shtml?url=javascript:alert`XSS`
https://share.trin.cam.ac.uk/sites/public/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?FollowSite=0&SiteName='-confirm(/XSS/)-'
http://www.rockwellautomation.com/global/news/the-journal/detail.page?docid=dfb8c8ba15e7cf2c599fc321b8e2b98e&G11N/Locale=en&geography=%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=x%20onerror=prompt%28/XSS/%29%3E&content_type=magazine&pagetitle=\n
https://www.ifishillinois.org/profiles/display_lake.php?waternum=1/*-/*`/*\`/*'/*"/**/--></script><svg/onload=;prompt(/XSS/);>00116
http://tools.xaa.su/htaccess/
http://www.wa.lk/realstate/product_display.php?id=%22%22;%3C%2Fscript%3E%3Cscript%3Eprompt(%2FXSS%2F)%3C%2Fscript%3E%3C%22
```

I need to extract all of the data which contains the string 'XSS' and put them into a list.

```
"><script>prompt(/XSS/)</script>
%22%3E%3Csvg/onload=alert(/XSS/)%3E
javascript:alert`XSS`
'-confirm(/XSS/)-'
```

and so on...

I have attempted to use urlparse but don't see this type of function anywhere

```
#from urllib.parse import urlparse
#
#url = 'http://user:pwd@NetLoc:80/path;param?query=arg#frag'
#parsed = urlparse(url)
#print('scheme  :', parsed.scheme)
#print('netloc  :', parsed.netloc)
#print('path    :', parsed.path)
#print('params  :', parsed.params)
#print('query   :', parsed.query)
#print('fragment:', parsed.fragment)
#print('username:', parsed.username)
#print('password:', parsed.password)
#print('hostname:', parsed.hostname)
#print('port    :', parsed.port)
```

I think

```
#print('params  :', parsed.params)
```

is the closest I can get, however, I don't want the parameter too.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the URLs in your example are valid (or at least conditionally valid). You can access the pieces of interest via a combination of `urlparse()` and `parse_qs()`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
from itertools import chain

pieces = list(chain(*[
              [item for item in chain(*parse_qs(urlparse(url).query).values()) 
               if 'XSS' in item] 
               for url in urls]))
#['"><svg/onload=alert(/XSS/)>', 
# 'javascript:alert`XSS`', 
# "'-confirm(/XSS/)-'", 
# '"><img src=x onerror=prompt(/XSS/)>']
```

Some URLs (e.g., the first one) are invalid. It is not clear what exactly you want to get from them. You may get more help if you provide a clear definition of the expected results.